# Beginner's question on OCL and derived attributes

Tags: ocl

I just recently started to look deeper into the intricacies of OCL. During my first applications, the following question came up:

Is it possible, and if so, what is the correct way to derive an attribute in case that no value is provided?

Approaches that came to my mind, but which may be formally incorrect were:

```
context   GenericClass::genericAttribute : PrimitiveType
derive:   if genericAttribute.oclIsUndefined() then
             <expression of matching type>
          endif
```

Another approach I could think of was

```
context   GenericClass::genericAttribute : PrimitiveType
inv:      genericAttribute.oclIsUndefined implies genericAttribute = <expression of matching type>
```

Admittedly, both approaches appear to be a bit awkward and thus I'd be happy if you could show me the formally correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term 'derived' is unfortunately overloaded. I presume that your usage here has nothing to do with inheritance, which is not available for properties - you need to delegate to a derived operation. Rather I assume you mean an automated computation.

Your first example is cyclic and so should fail, probably with a stack overflow. The invariant will probably detect and fail rather than correct the unsatisfied condition although an OCL implementation with global control and symbolic capabilities might get it 'right' once you have got past the illegal startup transient.

If you cannot use an 'init' clause to initialize then I suggest that you add a genericAttribute() operation that performs a clean access. If you rename the persisted attribute as rawGenericAttribute then you can re=use the genericAttribute spelling as a derived computation and avoid the confusion of same named attributes and operations.

(It is rarely necessary to use x.oclIsUndefined(). x <> null is clearer.)

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for your answer. Indeed, I am looking for an automated computation that is performed whenever there is no explicit value provided for the attribute. More precisely: I have a graph structure, in which the length of an edge can be explicitly set to an arbitrary value. If the length is not set (i.e. the value is null or '0'), the distance shall be the Euclidean Distance between the start and end node of the edges.

Comment: ok. In that case I would recommend an optionally set explicitLength attribute and a derived length computation.

Comment: Ok, can you add that to your answer so that I can mark my problem solvend?

Comment: No. I dislike non-trivial edits since they distort the thread. Comments IMHO often enhance an answer.